# How to run the window scroll event continuously?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to run the window scroll function continously to detect if a user scrolls down or scrolls up. How can I accomplish that with JS?

```
function doWork(){
window.onscroll = function(e) {
  // print "false" if direction is down and "true" if up
  console.log(this.oldScroll > this.scrollY);
  this.oldScroll = this.scrollY;
}}

var timer =  setInterval(doWork, 0);
```

Comment: You only need to set up the event handler **once**. No need for the interval timer.

Comment: What you're doing here is just repeating the setting of `window.onscroll`. Just set it once, it will trigger every time the user scrolls.

Answer (score 1):

Event handlers are called whenever the user initiates the event. You don't need to constantly be checking whether the event is happening. Think of it like a push notification, rather than a pull notification. Hence, something like this will work fine:

```
var oldScroll = 0;
window.addEventListener('scroll',function(event){
  console.log(oldScroll > window.scrollY);
  oldScroll = window.scrollY;
});
```

Notice that this uses `addEventListener`. This is generally good practise, as otherwise you will override any other functions that you have already assigned to the scroll event, instead of just adding your new function to the list. Hope this helps!